# Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence for path-loop fibration over Q\Sigma X (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, loop-spaces, cohomology-operations

Related to [the question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232443/the-behaviour-of-the-suspension-homomorphism-on-h-qxz-p-for-odd-p-refer), here is another question.  Consider the kernel of the map $H_*(QY;Z/p)\rightarrow H_{*+1}(Q\Sigma Y;Z/p)$. restricted to
$PH_*(QY)$, and let's say $Y$ itself is a suspension (as in the other question,
this extra hypothesis is not crucial).  By the quoted question,, all elements in 
the kernel are either in the image of $Q_0$, hence degree divisible by $2p$,
or in the image of $\beta Q_1$, hence degree congruent to $(-2)$ modulo $2p$.

This latter fact can be seen easily using the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence for the path-loop fibration over $Q\Sigma Y$: $QY\to pt \to Q\Sigma Y$.
The $E_2$ term looks like $$Cotor _{H_*(Q\Sigma Y;Z/p)}(Z/p,Z/p)\cong 
(Tor _{H^*(Q\Sigma Y;Z/p)}(Z/p,Z/p))^*.$$

However, by the computation of Dyer-Lashof, $H_*(Q\Sigma Y;Z/p)$ is of the form
$$H_*(Q\Sigma Y;Z/p)\cong P[x_i;i\in I]\otimes \Lambda (y_j;j\in J)$$
with all generators $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s primitive.
Thus by dualizing 
$$H^*(Q\Sigma Y;Z/p)\cong TP_1[(x_i^{p^m})^*;i\in I,m\in \mathbf{N}]\otimes \Lambda (y_j^*;j\in J)$$.
Therefore, the Tor group looks like 
$$Tor _{H^*(Q\Sigma Y;Z/p)}(Z/p,Z/p)\cong \Lambda (\sigma ^{-1}((x_i^{p^m})^*))\otimes \Gamma (\tau (x_i^{p^m})^*))
\otimes \Gamma (\sigma ^{-1}(y_j^*))$$ where $\tau $ denotes the transpotence.
All exterior generators have to survive to $E_{\infty}$ as all p-th powers in $H_*(Q\Sigma ^Y;Z/p)$ are known to be in the image of the homology suspension. 
SInce everything else is concentrated in even degrees, the spectral sequence collapses at $E_2$, and in homology, by dualizing we get

$$E_2=E_{\infty}\cong  \Lambda (\sigma ^{-1}((x_i^{p^m})))\otimes P (\tau (x_i^{p^m})^*))
\otimes P (\sigma ^{-1}(y_j^*)).$$
Thus the only polynomial generators that suspends trivially correspond
to the transpotence elements, having the internal degree divisible by $2p$ and homoogical degree $2$, so the total degree congruent to $(-2)$ mod $p$.  If we also consider "decomposable primitives", as there are also $p$-th powers, we arrive at the conclusion above.

My questions, now, are :

- Is there any reference for the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence for the path-loop fibration over $Q\Sigma X$ at odd primes?
- Is there any reference for the degrees of elements in the kernel of the suspension map for $QX$ (again, at odd primes)?